# How to keep 'Run tabs' open when I run another script in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, settings

I'm using PyCharm 2023.3.3 (Community Edition).

1. There is a Run tab which is completed and focused.
2. I run another script.
3. The completed tab just changes to another one.
4. So I lose logs on the completed tab.

I just want to run every script in a new tab so I don't lose logs accidentally.
I know I can Pin Tab to prevent this, but I want to fix default settings.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm, you can configure the behavior of the Run tool window to always open a new tab for each run configuration. Here's how you can do it:

1. Go to "File" > "Settings" (or "PyCharm" > "Preferences" on macOS).
2. In the Settings/Preferences dialog, navigate to "Tools" > "Run/Debug Configurations".
3. Look for the option called "Activate tool window" and select "Always" from the dropdown menu.
4. Click "OK" to apply the changes.

With this setting enabled, every time you run a script, it will open in a new tab in the Run tool window, preventing you from accidentally losing logs from previous runs.